# Failure using wunderground historical API

Tags: python, python-3.x, weather-api, wunderground

I am trying to use the wunderground api to have historical weather data by latitude and longitude.

Here is my python code:

```
import requests
import pprint

data = requests.get('http://api.wunderground.com/api/<MY_KEY>/history_199271/q/12.3,-95.9.json').json()
pprint.pprint(data)
```

Response:

```
{'response': {'error': {'description': 'No cities match your search query',
                    'type': 'querynotfound'},
          'features': {'history': 1},
          'termsofService': 'http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html',
          'version': '0.1'}}
```

Do you know what's wrong ?

**EDIT**: If you know any other API or python module that provides historical weather data by geographical coordinates it would also be fine.